# How to add an if then statement to a value with multiple arguments using bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am storing 2 values in my TMP location: `{time_total}` and `{http_code}`

I want to add an if-then condition that checks for the status. If it is anything other than 100, I want it to print out a line saying "something is wrong". But display nothing if the value is equal to 100.

```
echo getInfo  >> $SAVE_TO
for i in "${LB[@]}"
   do
        TMP=$(curl  -X GET -sS -w "%{time_total},%{http_code}\n" -H "UNAME:  
$USER" -H "UPASS: $PWD" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"propertytosearch":"systemUserName", "systemUserName":"XXXXXXX"}' https://$i/ws/rest/v2/getInfo -o /dev/null)
        echo ,$i,$TMP >> $SAVE_TO
   done

if [[ $http_code != $200 ]]
then
 echo "something wrong with $i"
fi
```

TMP Output:

```
1.207,100
```

If I remove `%{time}` and only use `%{status}`, the if-then command works. How would I do it for 2 input values?

I don't necessarily need to check for `{time}`, but if required, I can have an if condition for time that checks for anything greater than 4.000. It can have the same echo "something is wrong".

Comment: Instead of `"$100"` should use use `100`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills removing the " " did not work.

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used for the names of variables meaningful to the shell itself and POSIX-specified tools, whereas lowercase names are guaranteed safe for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: Is `SAVE_TO` supposed to demonstrate why you want to keep `TMP`? Why not `echo ",$i,$time,$status"` if you want to reconstruct the items?

Comment: ...btw, `>>anything` repeated in your script is a code smell -- much more efficient to just open a file once and reuse that open handle whenever you want to write another line instead of re-opening it over and over.

Answer (score 1):

To read `time` and `status` into two separate variables, you can do the following:

```
IFS=, read -r time status < <(curl  -X GET -sS -w "%{time},%{status}\n" -H)
```

...thereafter, you can test them individually:

```
if [[ $status != 100 ]]; then  # note that $status is safe unquoted only in [[ ]], not [ ]
  echo "Something is wrong"
fi
```

Comment: @hummingbirdtarry, the above code temporarily sets `IFS` only for the duration of the `read` command, to tell it how to distinguish where one field ends and the next one begins. I don't know what you mean referring to a "TMP command". See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a discussion of using `read`, explaining the meaning of `IFS` and the importance of `-r`.

Comment: @hummingbirdtarry, ...also, to better understand why we're using the `<(...)` syntax here, see [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), which describes what happens when trying to pipe directly to `read` without it.

Comment: I've updated my current code in the question. I am trying to apply IFS to the TMP value, but cannot find a way to set the field separator without interfering with the TMP command.

Comment: Why are you unwilling to change the assignment to `TMP`?

Comment: ...you can certainly run `IFS=, read -r time status <<<"$TMP"`, but the "why" question stands.

Comment: (For that matter, you could also refer to `${TMP%%,*}` and `${TMP##*,}` to refer to everything before the first `,` and everything after the last `,`, respectively).

Comment: The value of TMP is used in multiple other locations on the script. Not using TMP affects many other values, which is why I do not want to change it.

I did try using `IFS=, read -r time status <<<"$TMP"`, but it keeps toggling my output. 

If the http_code is anything other than 200, it should give me an error. But instead, if I use IFS, irrespective of the code being 200 or something else, it still throws the same message for all the conditions.

Comment: "Toggling my output"? Show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Logs generated from `bash -x yourscript` may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate each "element" individually like this

```
for element in ${TMP//,/ }
do
  if [ "$element" -ne 100 ]
  then
    echo Something is wrong.
  fi
done
```

Comment: I don't condone using string-splitting -- it's responsible for most of the bugs in [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) -- but if you *are* going to advise it, at minimum you can use bash-builtin string substitution: `for element in ${TMP//,/ }; do` is much more efficient than spinning up a subshell, setting up a pipeline in it, and running an external command such as `sed` inside that pipeline. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe, or [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).